# Check ToggleButton from Fragments

Tags: android

I want to use ToggleButton with tabbed activity.

I added ToggleButton  to my main activity toolbar.

How can I check ToggleButton in my tabbed fragment?

this is my code on mainactivity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_tabs);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

OneFragment:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

Edit:
I have added mainactivity and onefragment.

How can I check ToggleButton in onefragment?

Thank you for your help.

Edit2: github project https://github.com/jrxblu/tabtestt

Comment: the good way would be making your Activity implementing some custom `interface`, which you can call to return you the state of the toggle button in fragment., and in Fragment use `((YourInterface) getActivity()).getToggleButtonState()`

Comment: @vladyslav-matviienko what can go wrong if we directly cast context as MainActivity and access buttons from there?. I mean the fragment can never exist without an activity so, will it be fine?

Comment: it *can* exist without activity in fact - when it is not attached to activity. Also just a *context* might be non-Activity context, but for example Application context. Also Fragment should not manipulate activity. That's why it is better to use interface. @Deˣ has implemented my cmment into the answer, I encourage you to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface to read the `ToggleButton` state from Activity.

```
public interface ToggleButtonStateListener {
  boolean isChecked();
}
```

Implement in Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ToggleButtonStateListener {

  private TabLayout tabLayout;
  private ViewPager viewPager;
  private ToggleButton toggle;
  private OneFragment oneFragment;
  private TwoFragment twoFragment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_tabs);

    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    oneFragment = new OneFragment();
    oneFragment.setToggleListener(this);
    twoFragment = new TwoFragment();
    twoFragment.setToggleListener(this);

    adapter.addFragment(oneFragment, "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(twoFragment, "TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(oneFragment!= null) {
          oneFragment.performOnCheckOperation(isChecked);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChecked() {
    return toggle.isChecked();
  }

  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
      super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
      mFragmentList.add(fragment);
      mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
  }
}
```

Now in Fragment class whenever you need to know whether the toggle is checked or not use below code.

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    private ToggleButtonStateListener listener;

    public OneFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean isToggleChecked = listener.isChecked();//call to check toggle status
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onCreateView: "+isToggleChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    public void setToggleListener(ToggleButtonStateListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void performOnCheckOperation(boolean isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "performOnCheckOperation: "+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Two Fragment

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

    private ToggleButtonStateListener listener;

    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean isToggleChecked = listener.isChecked();//call to check toggle status
        if(isToggleChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+isToggleChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }

    public void setToggleListener(ToggleButtonStateListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

If you want to perform any action directly as soon as toggle check changes. You can create a method say `performOnCheckOperation` inside Fragment and call that inside OnCheckedChangeListener.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question, Can you help me about my code? Thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code but the app crash when start. " ToggleButtonStateListener.isChecked()' on a null object reference "

Comment: Did you do this ? ‘oneFragment.setOnToggleListener(this)’ Also see I have moved FindViewById line for toggle.

Comment: It should work. You might be missing something. Please check the code carefully.

Comment: Sorry its not work, I use this project SimpleTabsActivity https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: I need your help. @Deˣ

Comment: @EagleH Post the code on Github (if not confidential). I will take a look at it.

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: @EagleH I have updated the answer. Just copy-paste the classes. It should work.